# Python change instagram bio with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, xmlhttprequest, instagram

I'm trying to change my Instagram bio with a python post request, but it does not change. I don't get any errors, it only gives me a 200 response code but my bio stays the same. I copied all the headers from the POST request that I make when I edit my bio on instagram.com but it simply doesn't work.

```
import requests

url = "https://instagram.com/accounts/edit"

headers = {
  "authority" : "instagram.com",
  "accept" : "*/*",
  "accept-encoding" : "gzip, deflate, be",
  "accept-language" :  "en-US,en;q=0.9,bs;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,la;q=0.5",
  "content-length" : "207",
  "cookie" : "my-cookie",
  "origin" : "https://www.instagram.com",
  "referer" : "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit",
  "sec-fetch.dest" : "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode" : "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site" : "same-origin",
  "user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
  Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36",
  "x-csrftoken" : "my-token",
  "x-ig-app-id" : "app-id",
  "x-ig-www-claim" : "www-claim",
  "x-instagram-ajax" : "x-ajax",
  "x-requested-with" : "XMLHttpRequest",
}
body = {
  "first_name" : "my-name.",
  "email" : "my-email",
  "username" : "my-username",
  "phone_number" : "my-number",
  "biography" : "Hello world!",
  "external_url" : "",
  "chaining_enabled" : "on"
}
response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: You might need to send some cookies that say you are signed in...

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino thanks for the reply! I think I'm already sending the "signed in" cookie in the header

Comment: you should first use `get()` to get fresh cookies and you should create code which login to page. Cookies copied from browser can be outdated - server may change cookies every few minutes. Besides cookies may keep information about your browser and your script may not match to these information.

Comment: don't use `"content-length"` because `requests` should add this with correct value based on length of data in `data=`. If you add it manually with wrong value then server get wrong only part of data.